# A bug in relations with pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, relational-database

I need to make a relationship between User and Subscription table.
The user who registers gets a default free user and sees 1 an offer.
If silver see 8 offers, gold 15, platinum 20.
I made a relationship between user and subscription tables with a pivot table subscription_user.
The first question is whether I made a mistake somewhere in relation the model?
The second question is how to return only one offers by default, or if you subscribe to 8 offers (silver), 15 (gold), 20 (platinum) and in which controller?

User table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->string('subscription')->default('free');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Subscription table:

```
   Schema::create('subscriptions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('subscription');
        $table->integer('offers');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Sabscription_user table:

```
 Schema::create('subscription_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index(); //user table
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); //foreign key relation
        $table->integer('subscription_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->foreign('subscription_id')->references('id')->on('subscriptions')->onDelete('cascade'); //foreign key relation
    });
```

Subscription model:

```
class Subscription extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

User model:

```
public function subscriptions(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

Is everything connected as it should be for many to many relationship?
In which controller I can get information about offers?

Comment: Can a user have more than 1 subscription?

Comment: Do you get any error on the relationships? where is the bug? IMHO I would write a subscriptions() function inside the UserController

Comment: That he can have more than one subscription. @MattC

Comment: I don't know because I have not get information yet. Do you think I need a user controller? I have authController that controls login, register, logout. @dparoli

Comment: At the moment your model relationships are stating that a User can have MANY subscriptions. Is this correct? Or should a user only have 1 subscription at a time?

Comment: Ah my mistake.  I did not think about it. To save the user has only one subscription? One-to-more relation

Comment: But that is not so much important...I only for now need to connect my model and return subsciption..when I connect many-to-many tables and get data I will be able to solve it further.

Answer (score 2):

By convention the pivot table is named singular so you will need to specify by adding a second argument. I like to include all the arguments so there is no guessing anyway.

```
public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\Subscription", 'subscription_users', 'user_id', 'subscription_id', 'id',  'id');

}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("App\User", 'subscription_users', 'subscription_id', 'user_id', 'id',  'id');

}
```

Yes you should use a controller but it depends on where you are trying to display this. I imagine you will need to display the current subscriptions somewhere as well as add and remove.